# Проблема с ресурсами при подключении библиотеки как модуля

Tags: android, android-resources

вот из двух манифестов тег application. Этот  созданного модуля :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    tools:replace="android:label">
    <activity android:name=".MainMenu">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

и тег из подключенного модуля :

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.lamerman.FileDialog"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
</application>
```

В подключенном модуле  название приложения берется из строкового ресурса с таким же названием как и в моем модуле. Т.е. в каждом модуле есть строковый ресурс с одним названием , но разным значением. Я добавил `tools:replace="android:label"` и теперь название приложения берется из моего основного манифеста. Но строка считывается из ресурсов другого модуля. Почему? Это ведь очень не удобно если названия ресурсов не должны совпадать, каждый кто пишет модуль создает строковый ресурс с названием app_name. И правильно будет, если каждый модуль будет названия ресурсов сперва искать у себя. Наверно так и реализовано, но почему то  в моем случае не работает.

Comment: Проверьте локали строк и девайса - у меня как-то была такая проблема и дело было именно в этом.

Comment: Да и правда в подключенной библиотеке есть values-ru. Это значит, что  вместо того чтобы выбрать ресурс из своего модуля, выбирается ресурс из другого модуля, только потому что там есть русский язык?

Comment: Нельзя ли не тронув ничего указать чтобы ресурс брался из того же модуля где расположен сам основной манифест?

Comment: Можно сменить имя ресурса или продублировать локали в основном модуле

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При сборке приложения все ресурсы объединяются.
Из совпадающих
выбирается только один по приоритету (от большего к меньшему):

```
  build variant > build type > product flavor > main source set > library dependencies
```

При этом уникальность ресурса определяется не только по имени, но и по квалификатору.

Пример:

В основном модуле есть строка `appname` в `values`,
В зависимости тоже `appname` в `values` и `values-ru`.
В сборку попадёт `values` с `appname` из модуля
и `values-ru` с `appname` из зависимости.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources.html#resource_merging